# Laravel 5.3 обработка url запроса

Tags: php, laravel

С *Laravel v5.3* только знакомлюсь.

Помогите с решением вопроса: как можно обработать **GET** запрос вида: `/user/{uuid}/info` нужно достать из адресной строки `uuid` по нему обратится к базе данных и достать информацию по пользователю.

```
Route::get('/user/{uuid}/info', function () {
$uuid= Request::input('uuid'); - знаю что здесь ошибка.

if (Auth::attempt(array('id' => $uuid))){
    $userInfo = [
        'firstName' => Auth::user()->firstName,
        'lastName' => Auth::user()->lastName,
    ];
    return Redirect::to('userInfo')->with(Auth::user()->lastName);
} else {
    return Redirect::to('user/register');
}
});
```

Спасибо, за отклик.

Comment: входным аргументом для функции добавь переменную $uuid, и её и используй , ...function($uuid) {....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::get('/user/{uuid}/info', function ($uuid) {
// to do
});
```

попробуйте так

Если передается больше параметров то так:

```
Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', function ($postId, $commentId) {
    //
});
```

Названия не обязательно должны совпадать.

Comment: Спасибо, это оно, странно что не нашел примера в документации)

Comment: @Vlad плохо искали вот ссылка. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-parameters